# How to replace time stamp in the string and round hours?

Tags: javascript

I have function that returns array or values that represent working hours. Array can return one or two elements. In case where only one element is returned this is pretty simple but when I have two that is the problem to find the way how to replace the existing values in the string. Here is example of the original string: `0600-2200 MAY 15-SEP 30; 0600-2100 OCT 1-MAY 14`. I have function that finds the time stamp in the string and returns the hours. Example of the returning array is here: `[16,15]`. That array has two values and I need to replace `0600-2200` with first element in the array `16` and append the word `hours` to that. So final output should look like this: `16 hours MAY 15-SEP 30; 15 hours OCT 1-MAY 14`. Here is example of the function that converts time stamp to string:

```js
var timeSt = "0600-2200 MAY 15-SEP 30; 0600-2100 OCT 1-MAY 14";
const calcDifference = range => {
    const time = range.split`-`.map(e => (+e.substr(0, 2) * 60 + (+e.substr(2))) / 60);
    return time[1] - time[0];
};

const diffs = timeSt.match(/\d{4}\-\d{4}/g).map(e => calcDifference(e));
console.log(diffs);
```

The solution I have tried looks like this:

```
var hours = "";
for(var i=0; i < diffs.length; i++){
    hours += timeSt.replace(regex,diffs[i] + " hours ");
}
```

Here is the output that above example produced:

`16 hours MAY 15-SEP 30; 16 hours OCT 1-MAY 1415 hours MAY 15-SEP 30; 15 hours OCT 1-MAY 14`

Seems that entire string was appended twice. I understand why that is happening but still can't get a good way how to fix this problem. The other thing that I noticed is that some time stamp values look like this: `0000 - 2359`

In that case function that converts hours will return this: `[23.983333333333334]`. I would like to round up that value to `24` and that is the only case where the value should be rounded up to `24` the higer int his case. I time stamp looks like this: `0500-2330` function returns `[18.5]` and that value should not round. It should stay as it is. If anyone knows good way on how to fix these two problems please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the problem of replacing you can provide a callback to `.replace` function in string.

```
const roundMinutes = 15;
const timeSt = "0600-0000 MAY 15-SEP 30; 0600-2145 OCT 1-MAY 14";

const calcDifference = range => {
  const time = range.split`-`.map(e => +e.substr(0, 2) * 60 + (+e.substr(2)));
  let [start, end] = time;
  if (end < start) {
    end += 24 * 60;
  }
  return end - start;
};

const formatted = timeSt.replace(/\d{4}\-\d{4}/g, (range) => {
  const diff = calcDifference(range);
  const full = Math.round(diff / roundMinutes) * roundMinutes;
  const hours = Math.floor(full / 60);
  const minutes = full - hours * 60;
  const time = minutes === 0 ? `${hours}` : `${hours}.${minutes}`
  return `${time} hours`;
})

console.log(formatted)
```

To change precision you can tweak `roundMinutes` constant.

Comment: I'm afraid that would round values like `18.5` to `19` or I'm wrong?

Comment: @espresso_coffee Could you specify exactly how the rounding should work? I just tested this and it will always round up to the next hour.

Comment: If you read through the question you will find more information. I mentioned if time stamp is `2359` for example that should round up to `24`. If there is value like `1645` that should not round up. Basically anything that is not increment of 15 minutes should be round up. I hope this make sense.

Comment: I think that my previous feedback was not clear enough. If time stamp is anything similar to these values: `0530 - 2400` or `0745-1900` or `0415-2000` those should not round up. The only case where I want to round up the value is when it's like this: `0000-2359` or `1659-2200`. I hope this make sense.

Comment: @espresso_coffee right now it rounds to nearest 15 minutes (can be up or down), but I've made a change so you can tune to any number of minutes you want by changing `roundMinutes`

Comment: In case I want to present the `18.75` as `18.45` or `15.25` as `15.15` or `12.5` as `12.30` how we can convert that? Basically it should present number of minutes instead of integer. Also I found one problem with your code above. If time stamp is `0700-0000` it will return `-7`.

Comment: @Grassator The other thing I noticed this code is not working in Internet Explorer `(Edge,11,10)` is there a way to make this compatible in all browsers?

Comment: @espresso_coffee this code is uses ES2015 features. For backwards compatibility you can use https://babeljs.io either as part of your build pipeline or just once by copy-pasting the code into their online transpiler.